# Float statement is breaking a block level element?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the `I rate it ??/??` to be perfectly aligned in the center and floating in the left, so the `I rate it ??/??` word(s) will have a perfect vertical shape. When I do it, the **float statement breaks the block level element** and go outside of it. This is an example:

```css
li {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 10px;
}

span.rate {
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 65px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  float: right;
  background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Text1<span class="rate">I rate it 10/10</span></li>
  <li>Text2 Text Text Text Text Text<span class="rate">I rate it 6/10</span></li>
  <li>Text5<span class="rate">I rate it 9/10</span></li>
  <li>Text9 Text Text<span class="rate">I rate it 2/10</span></li>
</ol>
```

Here is another example, but without the `float` statement. It looks perfect, but without the `float: right;` statement, it's not vertically aligned at all. It's not perfectly aligned like the first one:

```css
li {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 10px;
}

span.rate {
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 65px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Text1<span class="rate">I rate it 10/10</span></li>
  <li>Text2 Text Text Text Text Text<span class="rate">I rate it 6/10</span></li>
  <li>Text5<span class="rate">I rate it 9/10</span></li>
  <li>Text9 Text Text<span class="rate">I rate it 2/10</span></li>
</ol>
```

In the end. I want the `I rate it ??/??` to be:

**1- Perfectly align vertically.**

**2- Perfectly fit inside the block level element.**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "Perfectly align vertically"? Align what, the text? In relation to what?

Comment: What I meant is I want the text to look like this:

Text Text Text                         I rate it 10/10
Text                                        I rate it 9/10
Text Text Text Text Text          I rate it 4/10

Instead of:

Text Text Text   I rate it 10/10
Text  I rate it 9/10
Text Text Text Text Text   I rate it 4/10

Comment: @LiquiKal Update your question. You cannot post formatting in comments

Comment: I noticed that, but why is that? And what do you mean update your question? I already refreshed multiple times.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. That is the way to tell users that you consider your own question solved. Note that other users might be of a different opinion, there might still be better answers coming up.

Comment: "Update your question." does not mean refresh. It means to [edit] the question to add information and take benefit from the much better formatting options offered that way (in contrast to the pitiful space and options in comments), as e.g. described here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mix `display: flex;` and `position: absolute;` to do so

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  background: green;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 10px;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;

}

span.rate {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
  width: 11ch;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Text1<span class="rate">I rate it 10/10</span></li>
  <li>Text2 Text Text Text Text Text<span class="rate">I rate it 6/10</span></li>
  <li>Text5<span class="rate">I rate it 9/10</span></li>
  <li>Text9 Text Text<span class="rate">I rate it 2/10</span></li>
</ol>
```

---

**EDIT:**

To avoid the text being hidden you could also use `display: grid;`

```css
li {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 11ch;
  background: green;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding-left: 10px ;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;

}

span.rate {
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
    background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
    width: 12ch;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Text1<span class="rate">I rate it 10/10</span></li>
  <li>Text2 Text Text Text Text Text<span class="rate">I rate it 6/10</span></li>
  <li>Text5<span class="rate">I rate it 9/10</span></li>
  <li>Text9 Text Text azlkejalzkje alkjez alkzj ealk zjeal zkjeal kzjea lzkej  eazmlk emalkz emaklz emlkaz melkaz emlkaz emlka zemlk 12345678<span class="rate">I rate it 2/10</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Theres several problems with this solution. Using `position: absolute` the rating floats over the text if you type in too much text it dissapears unde the rating box. if you expand the 10/10 to 100/100 it overflows and breaks. @LiquiKal, make sure that this is something that is not a problem to you.

Comment: @NilsKähler I edited the answer to prevent this from happening

Answer (score 2):

You could use flexbox to solve your problem.
Setting `display: flex` to make the element use flexbox, and then setting `justify-content: space-between;`(maximize space between elements) & `align-items: center;` (center the elements horizontally)

```css
li {
  display: flex;
  background: green;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

span.rate {
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 65px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Text1<span class="rate">I rate it 10/10</span></li>
  <li>Text2 Text Text Text Text Text<span class="rate">I rate it 6/10</span></li>
  <li>Text5<span class="rate">I rate it 9/10</span></li>
  <li>Text9 Text Text<span class="rate">I rate it 2/10</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you, @NilsKähler . You solved my problem.

Comment: is the 10/10 supposed to be wider than the rest?

Comment: @mplungjan, since the question went for how to align the items, i won't be the judge of that, the code snippet seems like it is for demonstration purposes, i pointed out the solution to the problem and try to isolate the solution to the problem, making this more usefull for future people with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use absolute & relative positioning. This way you have the most control over the positioning and will make sure the height is always 100%. Simple and clean.

```css
li {
  display: block;
  background: green;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 10px;
  position: relative;
}

span.rate {
  color: #fff;
  margin-right: 65px;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  background: rgb(10, 10, 10);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Text1<span class="rate">I rate it 10/10</span></li>
  <li>Text2 Text Text Text Text Text<span class="rate">I rate it 6/10</span></li>
  <li>Text5<span class="rate">I rate it 9/10</span></li>
  <li>Text9 Text Text<span class="rate">I rate it 2/10</span></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Your 10/10 is ALSO wider than the rest